# logback-test.xml and multi-module maven project

Tags: maven, maven-3, logback

In my maven project, I've got one module depending on another and it's test code/resources:

```
...
<scope>test</scope>
<type>test-jar</type>
...
```

Now, both modules have their own *logback-test.xml*, each having a specific configuration for running tests in that particular module. However, as expected, when running tests in child module, logback complains with a warning that there are multiple *logback-test.xml* in the path, AND does that with it's default logging configuration:

```
08:44:17,528 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
08:44:17,530 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback-test.xml] at [file:path/to/my/project/module2/logback-test.xml]
08:44:17,532 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback-test.xml] occurs multiple times on the classpath.
08:44:17,533 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback-test.xml] occurs at [file:/C:/path/to/my/project/module2/logback-test.xml]
08:44:17,533 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback-test.xml] occurs at [file:/C:/path/to/my/project/module1/logback-test.xml]
08:44:17,636 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
08:44:17,647 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
08:44:17,653 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [STDOUT]
08:44:17,692 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
08:44:17,764 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to WARN
08:44:17,764 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[ROOT]
08:44:17,765 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [com.myproject] to TRACE
08:44:17,765 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [ch.qos.logback] to OFF
08:44:17,768 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@5b0a485c - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
```

I wonder how could I solve this problem.. I want to keep multiple configurations for each module; I guess I can't exclude one file from classpath; I really just want to logback to shut up about things I'm aware of. As you can see from last two lines, I do have whole logback package on "OFF" in my configuration, but it still proceeds to log after that point. Log pattern is also different than I have configured in either configuration.

Logback is configured and used in code via SLF4J.

When running tests in parent module, none of this is logged (neither INFO nor WARN messages), so I can't blame it on anything else but strange Logback behaviour.

Answer (score 8):

You can exclude `logback-test.xml` from the test jar

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>test-jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <excludes>logback-test.xml</excludes>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>               
</plugin>
```

Or (I haven't tried this) you could use a naming convention `logback-test-project.a.xml`, `logback-test-project.b.xml` etc. and configure surefire differently in each project with `-Dlogback.configurationFile=logback-test-project.a.xml`.

Comment: the exclude solution solves problem just in one case: when running tests on one module, when all other dependencies are jars from repository. However, running one unit test from Eclipse (I guess this is the point where Maven has little to do with things), or running "clean test" on parent pom, are not affected by this configuration. Unfortunately, the former two are most frequent ways I run my test cases.

Comment: Does your parent POM have its own `logback-test` or is it purely an aggregator?

Comment: no, there's no code in parent. I was thinking about having just logging setup in parent, but I really want to have different logging settings for each module.

Comment: This was driving me nuts. Now each of our projects has a separate logback-<project>.xml and jvm opt for runtime. Sanity restored, thanks.

Comment: Dependencies on test jars is a bit of a pain; try moving the test code you want to re-use into its own proper module, then put its logback-test.xml into its proper place, `{module}/src/test/resources/logback-test.xml`, so that it's available only to the tests in this module, and also then `maven-jar-plugin` automatically excludes it from the jar artifact. Now your other modules can depend on this testing utility jar at the test scope. (I too started off with trying to re-use code from one test-jar in other tests in other modules, but eventually refactored it into its own module.)

Comment: This is a beautiful solution.